# Docker run command error

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, docker

I have just installed docker and pulled their official `ubuntu` image following their documentation installation tutorial.

However, when I get to the point of executing a command in a specific container, I end up with the following error:

`Error: Cannot start container f6e1084236794548bbd5cd059f46f916367106bf38ec24ad30ceefb9fb015291: fork/exec /var/lib/docker/containers/f6e1084236794548bbd5cd059f46f916367106bf38ec24ad30ceefb9fb015291/root/.dockerinit: invalid argument`

it happens either I run: `sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash` or just a simple `sudo docker run busybox echo hello world!`.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Thx.

Comment: I haven't, but maybe you can provide some more details on operating system, installation steps, etc.

Comment: I have installed it using their tutorial here: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-precise-12-04-lts-64-bit, the host operating system is ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit, theoretically it should be OK.

Comment: Which version of Docker are you using?  They just changed versions to 0.9.

Comment: `docker --version 0.9.0`

Comment: I experienced a similar problem with version 1.0.1

Comment: Do you experience that error if you try to run those commands as root?

Comment: lastest docker version is 1.2. Also when upgrading docker, I solved issues by deleting images built with former docker versions and rebuilding them (see `docker rmi` command)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a custom OVH kernel. [Installing](http://www.sysadminworld.com/2012/how-to-switch-to-the-standard-ubuntu-kernel-on-ovh/) a stock kernel helped.